# Error Occurs when attempting to assign taxonomy against the MiDAS database using the DADA2 package in R

Tags: r

When trying to assign taxonomy using the code:

```
taxa_midas_genus <- assignTaxonomy(seqtab.nochim, "C:/Users/.../MiDAS.fa",
+                                      taxLevels = c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus"),
+                                      verbose = TRUE,
+                                      tryRC = TRUE,
+                                      minBoot = 80) %>%
+ 
+     as_tibble(rownames = "sequence")
```

I receive the error: Error in if ((is.null(names) || any(bad_names <- duplicated(names) | names ==  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have attempted to use the If/else statement to try and solve this but the error always appears straight after the as.tibble line of code. Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: What happens if you only execute the first part of the command, without converting the tibble? If everything works fine you should get a data frame with the sequences and the corresponding taxa. Maybe the conversion to tibble is the problem.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I ran just the first part and it runs ok, but it outputs with the comment: "Finished processing reference fasta".

Comment: So the problem is in the tibble part. I suspect the correct name is "seq", not "sequence". Can you post the output of 'taxa_midas_genus[1:3,1:3]'?

Comment: Hi Fabio, I actually managed to fix it. I was missing a ".name_repair = "minimal" at the end